# Change values in <head> of HTML in Angular Dart

Tags: dart, angular-dart

so I am relatively new Angular Dart and Dart in general, and I am trying to create a simple webapp.

When I used to do PHP development I always had a config file that determined what environment the app was running on and decided to setup itself in different ways.

I am trying to figure how to achieve something similar in Angular Dart. Specifically as an example for the beginning I want to set different base href based on the URL that is loading the app. When you read the documentation it says that during development you should set the base href like this:

```
<script>
  // WARNING: DO NOT set the <base href> like this in production!
  // Details: https://webdev.dartlang.org/angular/guide/router
  (function () {
    var m = document.location.pathname.match(/^(\/[-\w]+)+\/web($|\/)/);
    document.write('<base href="' + (m ? m[0] : '/') + '" />');
  }());
</script>
```

But for distribution it should be set like this:

```
<base href="/">
```

All of this needs to be located in the `<head>` section of the HTML page so I would like to do some sort of an if statement here. Example how I wold do it in PHP:

```
<head>
   <?php if(DEV) { ?>
      // Do the development base href
   <?php } else if(PROD) { ?>
      // Do the production base href
   <?php }?>
</head>
```

So my question basically is, is something like this possible in Angular Dart at the moment ?

Answer (score 1):

You can't do binding in `<head>` with Angular.
I think there is still a way to pass "environment" variables to the app using `-D=PROD=...`
and then you could use `const isProd = bool.fromEnvironment('PROD')` (see also https://github.com/dart-lang/site-www/issues/404)
and then use `dart:html` to manipulate the DOM.

I haven't used this in web for a while and I'm not sure it's still supported in Dart 2.

(**Update found https://github.com/dart-lang/build/issues/1053**)

If `'<base href="...">` is only for Angular routing, then it's better to use

```
import 'package:angular_router/angular_router.dart';
```

and adding

```
ValueProvider<String>.forToken(appBaseHref, '/'),
```

to Angular providers.

I'm also using a build script that copies files like

```
cp web/run_config_prod.dart web/run_config.dart
webdev build ...
cp web/run_config_dev/run_config.dart
```

to have some settings changed depending on the target environment.

Comment: Thank you very much for the answer! While I understand the approach with the custom scripts, I will most definitely need to write some for my distribution as well. But I guess I am still curious as to how to change some stuff in the HTML head section. I've read somewhere that I can have multiple index.html and main.dart files. Is it possible for you to direct me to a tutorial how would I achieve that?

Comment: `import 'dart:html';` ... `document.head.querySelector(...).remove()` or `.children.add()` ... You can do everything JavaScript allows with Dart as well.

Comment: Yes, I am aware of that. But you are unable to manipulate the stuff that is in the <head> section per the dart documentation. So I willing to maintain multiple versions of my index.html and main.dart if that is possible?

Comment: Why do you think you are unable to manipulate `<head>`? One issue might be that it needs to be updated before even Dart code is executed to satisfy search engines or similar. In this case it's probably better to use multiple `index.html` files.

Comment: I appologize, my mistake. I was able to modify the title of the page with the `{{title}}` placeholder and latter binding it to a const value. But was unable to achieve the "if" statement. Can you maybe direct me in the right way of using multiple `index.html` files ?